# C# Error: OutOfMemoryException - Reading a large text file and replacing from dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, system.io.file

I'm new to C# and object-oriented programming in general. I have an application which parses text file.

The objective of the application is to read the contents of the provided text file and replace the matching values.

When a file about 800 MB to 1.2GB is provided as the input, the application crashes with error System.OutofMemoryException.

On researching, I came across couple of answers which recommend changing the **Target Platform: to x64**.

Same issue exists after changing the target platform.

Following is the code:

```
// Reading the text file
                var _data = string.Empty;
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(logF))
                {
                    _data = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    sr.Dispose();
                    sr.Close();
                }

                foreach (var replacement in replacements)
                {
                    _data = _data.Replace(replacement.Key, replacement.Value);
                }


                //Writing The text File
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(logF))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(_data);
                    sw.Dispose();
                    sw.Close();
                }
```

The error points to

> _data = sr.ReadToEnd();

replacements is a dictionary. The Key contains the original word and the Value contains the word to be replaced.

The Key elements are replaced with the Value elements of the KeyValuePair.

The approached being followed is Reading the file, replacing and writing.

I tried using a StringBuilder instead of string yet the application crashed.

Can this be overcome by reading the file one line at a time, replacing and writing? What would be the efficient and faster way of doing the same.

Update: The system memory is 8 GB and on monitoring the performance it spikes upto 100% memory usage.

@Tim Schmelter answer works well.

However, the memory utilization spikes over 90%. It could be due to the following code:

```
            String[] arrayofLine = File.ReadAllLines(logF);
            // Generating Replacement Information
            Dictionary<int, string> _replacementInfo = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayofLine.Length; i++)
            {
                foreach (var replacement in replacements.Keys)
                {
                    if (arrayofLine[i].Contains(replacement))
                    {
                        arrayofLine[i] = arrayofLine[i].Replace(replacement, masking[replacement]);
                        if (_replacementInfo.ContainsKey(i + 1))
                        {
                            _replacementInfo[i + 1] = _replacementInfo[i + 1] + "|" + replacement;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            _replacementInfo.Add(i + 1, replacement);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

//Creating Replacement Information
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (var Replacement in _replacementInfo)
                {
                    foreach (var replacement in Replacement.Value.Split('|'))
                    {
                        sb.AppendLine(string.Format("Line {0}: {1} ---> \t\t{2}", Replacement.Key, replacement, masking[replacement]));
                    }
                }

                // Writing the replacement information
                if (sb.Length!=0)
                { 
                using (StreamWriter swh = new StreamWriter(logF_Rep.txt))
                {
                    swh.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
                    swh.Dispose();
                    swh.Close();
                }
                }
                sb.Clear();
```

It finds the line number in which the replacement was made. Can this be captured using Tim's code in order to avoid loading the data into memory multiple times.

Comment: Please update your post to include the first few lines of the log file. How much RAM does your machine have?

Comment: Then, why don't read it line by line?

Comment: read line by line, right now you are bringing whole file data in memory which will cause failure if file size is greater than machine memory

Comment: Updated the post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have very large files you should try  [`MemoryMappedFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile(v=vs.110).aspx) which is designed for this purpose(files > 1GB) and enables to read "windows" of a file into memory. But it's not easy to use.

A simple optimization would be to read and replace line by line

```
int lineNumber = 0;
var _replacementInfo = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(logF))
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(logF_Temp))
    {
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            string line = sr.ReadLine();
            lineNumber++;
            foreach (var kv in replacements)
            {
                bool contains = line.Contains(kv.Key);
                if (contains)
                {
                    List<string> lineReplaceList;
                    if (!_replacementInfo.TryGetValue(lineNumber, out lineReplaceList))
                        lineReplaceList = new List<string>();
                    lineReplaceList.Add(kv.Key);
                    _replacementInfo[lineNumber] = lineReplaceList;

                    line = line.Replace(kv.Key, kv.Value);
                }
            }
            sw.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}
```

At the end you can use `File.Copy(logF_Temp, logF, true);` if you want to overwite the old.

Comment: you are not using the `vLineNumber` though

Comment: About `MemoryMappedFile` I worked with them and the posts of ayende helped me a lot https://ayende.com/blog/search?q=Memory+Mapped+Files

Comment: @Tim Schmelter The code works. Is it possible to capture the replacement information using the same code? The Line number in which the replacement was made? I have updated the post.

Comment: @Tango: your updated code contains `String[] arrayofLine = File.ReadAllLines(logF);`. That reads the whole file into memory. Why don't you use my code which reads only one line or `File.ReadLines` that also reads only one line.

Comment: @Tango: changed my code to add the line number info

Comment: @TimSchmelter I get the following error Additional information: An item with the same key has already been added.

Comment: @Tango: What you want to do if multiple replacements where done in the same line?

Comment: @TimSchmelter replace them with key value pair and make note of the line number

Comment: @Tango: you havent understood why the exception came. A dictionary can only contain unique keys, but my code added the same line number twice. The reason for it was that two strings were replaced in that line. I have now edited my answer to show you a different approach with a `_replacementInfo` dictionary of type `Dictionary<int, List<string>>`. So you can store multiple replacements for the same line.

Answer (score 0):

Read file line by line and append changed line to other file. At the end replace source file with new one (create backup or not).

```
var tmpFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(logF))
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(tmpFile))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            foreach (var replacement in replacements)
                line = line.Replace(replacement.Key, replacement.Value);

            sw.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}
File.Replace(tmpFile, logF, null);// you can pass backup file name instead on null if you want a backup of logF file
```

Answer (score -1):

An OutOfMemoryException is thrown whenever the application tries and fails to allocate memory to perform an operation. According to Microsoft's documentation, the following operations can potentially throw an OutOfMemoryException:

Boxing (i.e., wrapping a value type in an Object)
Creating an array
Creating an object
If you try to create an infinite number of objects, then it's pretty reasonable to assume that you're going to run out of memory sooner or later.

(Note: don't forget about the **garbage collector.** Depending on the lifetimes of the objects being created, it will delete some of them if it determines they're no longer in use.)

For What I suspect is this line :

```
  foreach (var replacement in replacements)
                {
                    _data = _data.Replace(replacement.Key, replacement.Value);
                }
```

That sooner or later u will run out of memory. Do u ever count how many it loop?

Try

- Increase the available memory.
- Reduce the amount of data you are    retrieving.